# How to use JSONP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

The example I am working with [can be found on this link](http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=myRun).

My JSONP content looks like so:

```
myRun (
{
"Status": "SUCCESS",
"Name": "Apple Inc",
"Symbol": "AAPL",
"LastPrice": 106.82,
"Open": 106.62
}
)
```

The code I am using below does not work. And I am not sure how to reorganize it to use JSONP.

```
var selfish = this;
$.getJSON('http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Quote/jsonp?symbol=AAPL&callback=myRun', function(data){
    console.log(selfish.data.Symbol);
});
```

Comment: read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for getJSON specifically how to make it JSONP - hint, you need something like `somecallback=?` as a search string in the URL ... the `?` being literally a `?` and `somecallback` depends on the API you are calling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "url",
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.error) {
                console.log ("data error:", data.error.errorMessage);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
       console.log ("ajax connection error:");
    }
});
```